# Unable to see spark error in logs in EMR Cluster

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a Amazon EMR spark cluster which was recently upgraded to `emr-6.9.0` and these are the applications available and their versions

```
Hadoop 3.3.3
Pig 0.17.0
Hue 4.10.0
Hive 3.1.3
JupyterEnterpriseGateway 2.6.0
Livy 0.7.1
Spark 3.3.0
```

When i submit jobs to the cluster using Livy, I'm not able to get clear error message in logs which i was able to get before upgrade as well as even now with EMR workspaces jupyter notebooks. The only info i see is this

```
23/09/05 01:12:11 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User application exited with status 1
23/09/05 01:12:11 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 1, (reason: User application exited with status 1)
```

Is there any thing i can do to get clear logs about failure?

ps: If needed, I'll try to add other details to debug this issue.